# node.js - gm for node.js .thumb() does not cut exact size

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

GraphicsMagick for node.js has a method of making thumbnails, written like this in the docs

```
gm("img.png").thumb(width, height, outName, quality, callback)
```

For width and height are "minimum value"? http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#thumb

The function does not generate an exact size specified. If I input

```
gm("img.png").thumb(200, 200, ...)
```

I will have chances to get the following dimensions:

- 200x200
- 200x199
- 199x200

**How can I make exact size thumbnails using gm?** Please help :(

Comment: Use [`resize`](http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#resize)?

Comment: @robertklep, but thumb() would export a file to the `outName` meaning the file is written. Do you mean I have to load the file again?

Comment: Add a `.write(outName)` to the command chain, that's basically that `.thumb()` does too (see [here](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/blob/18ef222080d3bc498adff2bb2264b171c4345619/lib/convenience/thumb.js#L61-L70)).

Comment: @robertklep do you mean I leave out the `outName` parameter and add a `.write()` after `.thumb(width, height, outName, quality, callback)` like `.thumb().write()`? Wouldn't it execute 2 `.write()` functions?

Comment: No, it would apply to situations where you would use `resize`: `gm(...).resize(...).write(outName)`

Comment: @robertklep I'm seriously not getting you :/ Can you make an example with making a thumbnail of "img.jpg", 200x200?

Comment: You probably want `.extent()` anyway, since `.resize()` will break the image's aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making a thumb using the `.thumb()` function, use `.extent(width, height)`.
In your case, width and height will both be 200. This will paint the picture on a 200x200 canvas centering it automatically if the aspect ratio does not match this size.

I wrote this sample code to create a 200x200 thumbnail from an image that does not meet the aspect ratio requirement without using the .thumb() function. Options is {height: 200, width: 200}

```
inputImage = inputImage.resize(options.width, options.height, "^"); //^ is the type of resize string
inputImage = inputImage.gravity("Center");
inputImage = inputImage.extent(options.width, options.height);
```

Input Image - https://www.travelalaska.com/~/media/Images/Travel%20Alaska/Content/HomePage/GlacierBay.jpg

Output Image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/cARDo.png
[image]

Comment: would there be a blank line, because it extends a 200x199 to a 200x200?

Comment: Also, thumb() would export a file to the `outName` meaning the file is written. Do you mean I have to load the file again?

Comment: Can you make an example with making a thumbnail of "img.jpg", 200x200?

Comment: Have added a sample code to create a thumbnail with input and output image